# This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio for vs2013 ultimate from vs2013 express

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I am currently running vs2013 ultimate Update 5, updated recently, from my laptop and another developer is running vs2013 express on their machine.  Up to this point I have been able to pull the project down from our GitHub repository and open the solution which contains one web project (ASP.NET mvc4).

Recently, my hard drive failed and I had to restore my mac computer to its latest backup point.  Since then, I have not been able to open the web solution.  I keep getting the following error message "This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio."  There is an icon of a blue diamond to the left of the project name and an exclamation point in the blue diamond and the words "(incompatible)" the the right of the project name.

When I open the ".csproj" file the ToolsVersion is set to "4.0".

The ProjectTypeGuids are as follows `"<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>"`.

The target frame version is as follows, "v4.5".

If I view the HTML log page that is generated I receive "The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47".

I have tried several things from changing the TargetFrameworkVersion to changing the ToolsVersion.  I tried to remove the first guid from the ProjectTypeGuids element, this did not work.  I even tried to run a repair on vs2013 from "Programs and Features".  I need this running for several items, I need to test on my local machine.

One thing is strange, I do not see a registry entry for "E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47".  What could I do to add this registry entry for vs2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have not the web development tools installed. Run the Visual Studio installer to modify the installed components. Make sure that web development tools are selected and then update the installation.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.  I have been stuck on that since yesterday morning.